# Python 3.6.X: Different values of from timestamp on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp

Following script gives different output on Windows and Linux OS.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 10, 12, 57, 4).timestamp()
```

Followings are the output depending on os

- On Windows, 13866**604**24.0
- On Linux, 13866**802**24.0

I am curious to know why there is a difference?

Comment: Your windows result looks way off, the times won't match up with even with `UTC`.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks for your response sir, actually time difference is exactly the same as the difference between local timezone and UTC which is `330` minutes.

Comment: Where do you live? I've never heard such a thing. If I'm here and it's `12:57` somewhere else it might be `5:57` or `7:57`, etc., although I didn't think it could be `12:57` here while it's `5:27` elsewhere.

Comment: India.  As `IST` is  `(UTC +5:30) ` so there is a difference of `330` min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!
If you see time difference it's `seconds = 19800` or `minutes=330` or `hrs=5:30`
Two machines can have different timezone setting.
Use UTC timezone to compare timestamp.
eg.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime(2013, 12, 10, 12, 57, 4, 0, timezone.utc).timestamp()
```